# Is there a way I can generate a list of all entities in CRM and if they have audit history turned on or not?

Tags: c#, sql-server, dynamics-crm, crm

I checked an entity in the CRM SQL database but there wasn't a column specifying about audit history.  I know there is a way to enable / disable it through CRM's online portal but that would take a pretty long time to see which entities have it enabled and which have it disabled.

I've tried poking around but couldn't find much on the topic so I figured I'd see if anyone here knew anything about it or had any experience with it.

Here is a quote from Microsoft's page on accessing it through the online portal:

> Click the entity for which you want to start or stop auditing. To start auditing, on the General tab, in the Data Services section, select the Auditing check box. To stop auditing, clear the check box.

http://crmbook.powerobjects.com/basics/data-management-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/auditing-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm/

Let me know if there is anything I can add to make my question more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Referring you once again to the XrmToolbox....  The MetaData Browser does what you're looking for:

[image: Metadata Browser Example]

Please note that for this screenshot I used the Columns button to move the IsAuditEnabled column as far to the left as possible.

And since you indicated that you have access to SQL, here's a query:

```
SELECT EntityId, Name, IsAudited
FROM MyOrg_MSCRM.MetadataSchema.Entity
```

If you're looking to do this in C#, the [RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.messages.retrieveallentitiesrequest.aspx) class is a good starting point.

Comment: I was just getting ready to manually type everything out because it wouldn't let me copy / paste or export from the MetaDataBroweser.  That query saved me a ton of time! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Download [XrmToolBox](http://www.xrmtoolbox.com) & enable/disable audit in single stretch.

Audit center plugin will help you to complete the magic.

[Read more](http://mscrmtools.blogspot.com/2013/08/new-xrmtoolbox-plugin-audit-center.html)

**Update:**
After you install the xrmtoolbox, Connect to Org, Click 'Audit center', Click 'Load data' - Audited entities & attributes will be listed:

[image: Tool snip]

Comment: Thank you for the response Arun, that will definitely be helpful to me down the road.  However for now I am just seeking to generate a list of entities and if they have that audit history enabled or disabled.  I do not need to turn them on or off just yet.

Comment: After you install the xrmtoolbox, connect to org, Click Audit center, Audited entities & attributes will be listed after clicking Load data.

Answer (score 0):

Use XRMToolbox tool called SQL 4 CDS and use the below query to get all the entities and attributes where Audit is enabled. You can copy the data to excelsheet and off you go. Good Luck.

```
  SELECT attribute.displayname AS "Attribute Display Name",
       attribute.logicalname AS "Attribute Logical Name",
       entity.displayname AS 'Entity Display Name',
       attribute.entitylogicalname AS "Entity Logical Name"
FROM   attribute
       INNER JOIN
       entity
       ON attribute.entitylogicalname = entity.logicalname
WHERE  attribute.isauditenabled = 1
and entity.isauditenabled =1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add "Pascalcase Metadata Browser" to the browser which helps you check for tables:

[image: Fieldoncedownloadedtoexcel]

[image: StepstocheckauditenabledfieldusingPascalcase Metadata Browser]

Answer (score -1):

```sql
SELECT  E.displayname, E.logicalname FROM metadata.entity E
WHERE E.isauditenabled = 1
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).